# How to keep drop down menu variable by function

Tags: javascript, html

i have a function with 3 cases depending on the date. Now i want to display it in a drop down menu.

```
function get_data_date(i) {
var string;
if (i == 0) {
  if(d.getUTCHours() < 3 ) {
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
              string=d_date.getUTCFullYear()+""+addZero1(d_date.getUTCMonth()+1)+""+d_date.getUTCDate()+"_"+addZero1(d_date.getUTCHours());

return string;
}
```

I do not know how to call the function in an Option tag. Please note that the function is not complete displayed.

```
 <form action="select.htm">

    <select name="run" size="1">
    <option id="run1" > get_data_date(0)</option>
    <option id="run2" > get_data_date(1) </option>
    <option id="run3" > get_data_date(2)</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: $('#run1').text(get_data_date(0)),$('#run2').text(get_data_date(1)), $('#run3').text(get_data_date(2)).. if you use Jquery

Comment: see [how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string) --> you'll want to move the arguments portion out of the option text

Comment: I searched for "onload"

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `eval`, as it offers too many opportunities for Bad Things.

Instead, inspect the selected `option` and invoke the appropriate function. With the markup as you've presented it, it would look something like this

```js
// Ignore this, it's just here for an example
var doLog = (function() {
  var logOutput = document.createElement('pre');
  document.body.appendChild(logOutput);
  return function doLog(msg) {
    var t = document.createTextNode(msg + "\n");
    logOutput.appendChild(t);
  };
})();

function get_data_date(i) {
  doLog('You selected ' + i);
}

function selectChangeHandler(ev) {
  var e = ev.target;
  var id = e.options[e.selectedIndex].id;

  // Invoke `get_data_date` with appropriate argument, based on
  // the selected option. NOTE: This is not a good solution--see below for
  // a better one
  if (id === 'run1') {
    get_data_date(0);
  } else if (id === 'run2') {
    get_data_date(1);
  } else if (id === 'run3') {
    get_data_date(2);
  }

}

var selectControl = document.querySelector('select[name="run"]');

selectControl.addEventListener('change', selectChangeHandler);
```

```html
<form action="select.htm">
  <select name="run" size="1">
    <option id="run1" > get_data_date(0)</option>
    <option id="run2" > get_data_date(1) </option>
    <option id="run3" > get_data_date(2)</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

However, if you have control of your markup, you should consider refactoring to put the value you care about in the `value` attribute of your `option`s. Then, you can directly access that value and pass it as an argument to your function.

```js
// Ignore this, it's just here for an example
var doLog = (function() {
  var logOutput = document.createElement('pre');
  document.body.appendChild(logOutput);
  return function doLog(msg) {
    var t = document.createTextNode(msg + "\n");
    logOutput.appendChild(t);
  };
})();

function get_data_date(i) {
  doLog('You selected ' + i);
}

function selectChangeHandler(ev) {
  var e = ev.target;
  // TODO: Error handling
  var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  get_data_date(val);
}

var selectControl = document.getElementById('date-run-select');

selectControl.addEventListener('change', selectChangeHandler);
```

```html
<form action="select.htm">
  <select id="date-run-select" name="run" size="1">
    <option id="run1" value="0"> get_data_date(0)</option>
    <option id="run2" value="1"> get_data_date(1) </option>
    <option id="run3" value="2"> get_data_date(2)</option>
  </select>
</form>
```